# Performance of ReentrantReadWriteLock read lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, synchronization, jmh

I have some storage similar to a map. I have been using `synchronized(this)` for `get` and `put` methods. Since this storage is mostly used for reading, I thought of using `ReentrantReadWriteLock` for better performance - to lock only on `put`.

I expected better performance on lookups (since storage content was not changed). However, my JMH test shows the opposite:

```
.benchmarkClassMap3ClassLookup    thrpt       20    460.152        7.417  ops/ms
.benchmarkClassMapClassLookup     thrpt       20   1196.085       23.635  ops/ms
```

The first line is for the code using `ReentrantReadWriteLock`. The second line is for the original code, with `synchronized`. EDIT: test was running with 2 threads.

Did anyone else benchmarked `ReentrantReadWriteLock`? Shouldn't be the results different? Or do the positive result only show up in the multi-threaded environment?

Related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637170/reentrantreadwritelock-vs-synchronized).

Comment: What jdk do you use?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_67"

Comment: Though your data is just _like_ a map, did you consder ConcurrentHashMap? At least for comparison.

Comment: @JoopEggen same performances as my implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need for sure multiple threads to see a benefit because [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) is more complex than the simple `synchronized`. In case of `synchronized` the JVM might optimize and remove the synchronization all together if it sees that there is only one thread. But here is also a quote from ReentrantReadWriteLock javadoc:

> ReentrantReadWriteLocks can be used to improve concurrency in some
>   uses of some kinds of Collections. This is typically worthwhile only
>   when the collections are expected to be large, accessed by more reader
>   threads than writer threads, and entail operations with overhead that
>   outweighs synchronization overhead.

If you afford to move to Java 8 you can replace `ReentrantReadWriteLock` with the new [StampedLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) that came with this release. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26075089/895215) for a short example and benefits.

Comment: Thanx. I made a mistake, my tests were running with 2 active threads. BTW, here is an [interesting article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/06/java-8-stampedlocks-vs-readwritelocks-and-synchronized.html)